# Get first n text characters of a web page with their styles etc

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to get the first n characters of a web page and display them as they are displayed in the original document.

I thought of using `textContent` in JavaScript to get the text, and then somehow recursively get all the DOM (I hope that's the right term) without the text. But it seems that recombining them will be very difficult.

Also, perhaps there's a simple way to achieve this. So why reinvent the wheel?

So how *can* it be done? (I'm not asking for the whole code, just for an approach to solve this.)

Comment: Are you wanting to do this in Javascript or ASP?

Comment: What do you mean by "the first n (-any number) characters"

Comment: @Titanium For example - The page might have 1000 characters - And I want to show the first 500 with the same formatting etc. as they are shown when the whole page is shown.

Comment: [Is there a chance to get first 40 chars with style (color and font-weight)](http://jsfiddle.net/qcrZe/).

Comment: @SheikhHeera I don't understand your comment.

Comment: I would suggest to limit not characters, but height. As content is still loaded (to properly format the elements), performance is not the issue. So put content in div, set `height` and add `overflow:hidden`.

Comment: In the given link there are some texts in two `divs` and some open with different colors, now do you need to get 40 characters (40 for example) with there style ?

Comment: With `CSS` styling, this is a little bit complex. I imagine you'd have to get each `CSS` property, or include each `CSS` and `JS` file and include the `HTML` as it is on the page.  And if you limit the characters, you'll have trouble with ending tags properly.

Comment: @Titanium It will all be done on that page so I can simply use the same CSS classes etc. And, yes, I'll need _all_ of the tags intact.

Comment: @barius "As content is still loaded" - I can do it after all is loaded but before being shown (If that's possible).

Comment: @SheikhHeera I have added a demonstration that uses your HTML.

Answer (score 2):

The following code removes all text after the first 35 characters in a document. It ignores non visible text and text nodes that are entirely composed of whitespace. You can see a demonstration of it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/tjH76/):

```
var limit = 35;
var current = 0;

function recurse(element) {
  if (element.childNodes.length > 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < element.childNodes.length; i++) {
      recurse(element.childNodes[i]);
    }
  }

  if (element.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE && element.nodeValue.trim() != '' && window.getComputedStyle(element.parentElement).height != "auto") {
    var length = element.nodeValue.length;
    if (current < limit) {
      if(current + length > limit){
        element.nodeValue = element.nodeValue.substr(0, limit - current)
      }
      current += length;
    } else {
      element.nodeValue = "";
    }
  }
}
var html = document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0];
recurse(html);
```